# React native: createStackNavigator overlaps on the actual screen contents (Android)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating a sample hotels listing application with following menus:

```
export const loggedInMenu = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Hotels: {
      screen: hotelDetailsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Hotels",
        tabBarIcon: <Icon name="hotel" size={24} />
      }
    },
    HotelsSearch: {
      screen: HotelsSearch,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Search",
        tabBarIcon: <Icon name="search" size={24} />
      }
    },
    Favourites: {
      screen: Favourites,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Hotels",
        tabBarIcon: <Icon name="favorite" size={24} />
      }
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Hotels'
  }
);

export const hotelDetailsScreen = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Hotels: {screen: Hotels},
    hotelDetails: {screen: hotelDetails},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Hotels",
    headerLayoutPreset: "center",
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Hotels",
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#694fad'
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The code works, however with one exception that the initial hotels screen header is overlapping the view data. Any help appreciated.

Check the below output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) was misleading (at least for me). I specified `headerTransparent: true,` which was Not needed as I just wanted to set the background color on the screen. I removed it and started working well.